# What is the significance of MinFreeMemoryPercentageToActivateService in WCF?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, memory-management

We recently had some memory related issues wherein our WCF services failed to compile due to shortage of free memory. We came across this property [MinFreeMemoryPercentageToActivateService](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.configuration.servicehostingenvironmentsection.minfreememorypercentagetoactivateservice%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) 
which specifies the minimum amount of free memory that should be available to the system, before a Windows Communication Foundation (WCF) service can be activated. By default, this is set to 5%. Is it a good practice to reduce this to say 1%? What could be the repercussions of reducing this value?

Answer (score 2):

You could reduce it to 1% and things may actually run. But a bigger question is why you have so little memory. Even if the web service starts, it may turn out to be unresponsive, too slow, etc. because of problems with insufficient memory. This setting is meant to be a safeguard to guarantee a minimum level of performance from the web service.